# How can one compute the quantum motion of an ion in a trapped ion quantum computer?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, momentum, quantum-optics, quantum-computer

I am trying to get a conceptual idea of a trapped ion quantum computer.
For simplicity, I am looking at a single ion in a Paul ion trap.
It is easy enough to define the potential of the ion trap and compute a Schrödinger wave function for the isolated ion to subsequently compute the probabilities for position and momentum of the ion in space.
However, I have a hard time understanding what happens once you turn the laser on.
The atom is continuously illuminated by the laser and the experiment measures the light that is emitted and scattered by the ion.
But this means that the ion becomes entangled with its environment.
The measurement is certainly not continuous, but I assume that it happens at a high frequency and my understanding is that the wave function collapse of the ion must happen with the same frequency.

How can I compute the position and momentum probabilities of the ion under these circumstances?
Does it even make sense to speak of position and momentum of the ion in this context?

Comment: Couldn't you write down the Hamiltonian of the atom + laser system and work out the eigenstates? The rest should be straightforward.

Comment: That was my first thought as well, but my understanding so far is that the dynamics of the ion are not unitary anymore, since its measurement is almost continuous.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by the dynamics not being unitary? The Hamiltonian of a physical system must be unitary, which is a necessary condition for the eigenvalues to be real.

Comment: The way I understand it so far, the dynamics of the full system are still unitary, but you're not looking at the full system anymore, you can't accurately account for all degrees of freedom.